# express decorator classes for routes are not being executed

Tags: typescript, express, webpack, decorator

i have been writing custom decorators for express controllers. Decorator classes are not being executed. I checked the bundle.js and decorator code was bundled inside bundle.js

```
@controller("/api/v1/portfolios")
 class PortfolioController {
  @get("")
  async getPortfolios(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const portfolios = await Portfolio.find({});
    return res.json(portfolios);
  }}
```

i imported this in app.js

```
const server = express();
import("./controllers/portfolios");
server.use(AppRouter.getInstance());
```

router is a singleton object.

```
export class AppRouter {
  private static instance: express.Router;
  static getInstance(): express.Router {
    if (!AppRouter.instance) {
      AppRouter.instance = express.Router();
    }
    return AppRouter.instance;
  }
}
```

this is the controller decorator

```
export function controller(routePrefix: string) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    const router = AppRouter.getInstance();
    for (let key in target.prototype) {
      const routeHandler = target.prototype[key]; //getLogin
      const path = Reflect.getMetadata(
        MetadataKeys.Path,
        target.prototype,
        key
      );
      const method: Methods = Reflect.getMetadata(
        MetadataKeys.Method,
        target.prototype,
        key
      );
      const middlewares =
        Reflect.getMetadata(MetadataKeys.Middleware, target.prototype, key) ||
        [];
      if (path) {
        router[method](
          `${routePrefix}${path}`,
          ...middlewares,
          //   validator,
          routeHandler
        );
      }
    }
  };
}
```

this is the webpack.config.json

```
const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const nodeWebExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["regenerator-runtime/runtime", "./src/index.ts"],
  mode: "development",
  target: "node",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ }],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".json"],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"), "node_modules"],
  },
  externals: [nodeWebExternals()],
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
};
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot GET /api/v1/blogs
```